# Oracle NOT BETWEEN for string comparison does not give same result as <= and >=

Tags: oracle, comparison-operators

Using Oracle 11gR2 Expression Edition.
My data looks like following

```
ordertype
---------
ZOCO
ZOSA
ZOST
```

We are trying to find out records where the column is not between a certain range of values.

If I run a query with <= and >= operators:
`SELECT * FROM table where ordertype <= 'ZAAA' OR ordertype >= 'ZZZZ';`
 then I get 0 results. *This is the right answer.*

However, if I use NOT BETWEEN:
`SELECT * FROM table where ordertype NOT BETWEEN 'ZAAA' AND 'ZZZZ';`
, then it gives multiple hits.

My understanding is that both syntax should give the same result but they are not. What am I missing? Reason I want to use NOT BETWEEN because a lot of our existing code already has this syntax and I do not want to change it without understanding the reasons.

Thank you.

---

Thanks for all those who posted. I ran the queries again and after fixing the "OR" in the first query, the results are the same. I still have the question of why Oracle character sorting is not recognizing it as expected, but my question which is about difference between NOT BETWEEN and <> was a false alarm. I apologize for confusion.

Comment: My apologies for the typo in my question above. The first query I meant to write was ordertype <= 'ZAAA' OR ordertype >= 'ZZZZ'

Comment: Thanks for all those who posted. I ran the queries again and after fixing the "OR" in the first query, the results are the same. I still have the question of why Oracle character sorting is not recognizing it as expected, but my question which is about difference between NOT BETWEEN and <> was a false alarm.

Comment: Now, after your changing the `and` into an `or`, I am quite convinced that both statements do indeed return the same records. Could you please run http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8ac4/1 and tell us which records are returned. Also, do a `select dump(ordertype) from table where ordertype NOT BETWEEN 'ZAAA' AND 'ZZZZ';` and post the result.

Comment: @René Clearly there was something strange here. Very good idea to require a `DUMP`.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT * FROM table where ordertype <= 'ZAAA' AND ordertype >= 'ZZZZ';
```

No string can be <= 'ZAAA' **and** >= 'ZZZZ'.
You need to use a disjunction instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table where ordertype < 'ZAAA' OR ordertype > 'ZZZZ';
```

<sup>BTW, given that `BETWEEN` is inclusive, `NOT BETWEEN` is exclusive</sup>

---

This is a common pitfall. you have to remember the [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> **`not (A and B)`** is the same as **`(not A) or (not B)`**

Feel free to experiment with this simple live example to convince yourself that those results are quite coherent: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38326

---

That being said, the only way (I can see) for the string like `ZOCO` for *not* being between `ZAAA` and `ZZZZ` would be:

- having some hidden character just behind the `Z` (i.e.: `'Z'||CHR(0)||'OCO'`)
- *or* using a *locale* such as `Z`-something is actually considered as a different letter, with a collation order outside of the given range. I don't know if such locale exists, but for example, in Welch, `LL` is considered as a single letter that should be sorted after the plain `L`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order#Language-specific_conventions
- *or* having [homogplyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph) such as `0`,  or `О` instead of `O` in your data.

Comment: (a distant sound of a facepalm) 30 years of programming exp, a degree in computer science, yet I couldn't spot this. :-) A clear symptom of me being exhausted. +1 for nicely explained answer.

Comment: Hi Sylvain, thanks for pointing out - I have corrected my first query - I am trying to query where ordertype < 'ZAAA' or ordertype > 'ZZZZ'. Having said that, I didn't understand the comment about DeMorgan's law. NOT BETWEEN 'ZAAA' AND 'ZZZZ' based on your comment above is translated as (NOT ordetype > 'ZAAA') OR (NOT ordertype < 'ZZZZ'). ZOCO would give for that (false) or (false) - so it should not return ZOCO as a result from that query.

Comment: @user3208146 I'm sorry, I can't tell you much more than that: if `'ZOCO' BETWEEN 'ZAAA' AND 'ZZZZ'` is _false_ the only explanations that could came to my mind are those I gave in the second part of my answer. Either some hidden char -- or a collation considering the `ZO` digraph as separate letter -- or homoglyphs.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding that both statements are same is incorrect. `NOT BETWEEN` is not evaluated the way you're thinking. It simply returns the results which fall outside evaluation of `BETWEEN` for the parameters.

IF you check Oracle documentation for *BETWEEN*, it says -

```
The value of

expr1 NOT BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3
is the value of the expression

NOT (expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3)
```

Comment: No, `NOT BETWEEN` should not return all records. The records that are between `ZAAA` and `ZZZZ` (such as `ZBCD`) would not be returned in both statements.

Comment: Thanks Rene. So in my example - ZOCO is between ZAAA and ZZZZ based on Oracle character sort so NOT BETWEEN should not return ZOCO, right?

Answer (score 3):

If it's not between the values, it has to be either < OR >, not AND.

Answer (score 3):

In the first query, you ask for the records that are at the same time less than `'ZAAA'` *and also* greater than `'ZZZZ'`. Of course, there is no such value that fullfills both requirements, hence zero records are returned.

In the second query, you ask for records, that are *either* less than `'ZAAA'` *or* greater than `'ZZZZ'` (ie not between those boundaries [`not between...`]). There is a possibility that such records exist, and as your select statement proves, there are indeed such records, that are returned by the statement.

Comment: I had incorrectly written my question. The first query should be ordertype < 'ZAAA' OR ordertype > 'ZZZZ' and the second ordertype NOT BETWEEN 'ZAAA' AND 'ZZZZ'.